# several similar forms - best practices

Tags: asp.net

I have a website with several forms that have similar items: title, name, company, occupation,  etc...

What is the best practice for creating these? I guess hardcoding these in every form would be a bad idea... I was thinking on storing the items in an external file or maybe a using a .resx file...

any ideas?

Comment: I love DRY principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a `UserControl`.ascx file as a template for those fields? You can reuse this UserControls in all forms you want and you will have a single place to change when needed.

Comment: I tried this and the problem is that you can't reference the controls from the code behind of the file that contains them... any other ideas?

Comment: @user441365: There are two way to do references to the inside controllers. First, you can use user_control_name.FindControl("textBoxId"). The second way is to add properties to your UserControl, like this: public TextBox EmailText { get { return EmailTextBox; } }. By this way, you can have access through user_control_name.EmailText.Text, for example.

Answer (score 0):

A language table in the DB could work.